# Am I formatting my input data optimally for an LSTM in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am using an LSTM model for time-series forecasting and implementing it with Keras in Python. My model takes in the previous weeks observations at half hour intervals in order to predict the value 24 hours ahead. I am unsure as to whether my input data is optimal or correct. I have a feeling it is correct as I am getting pretty ok results, but hoping for better.

My input data is a CSV file which is just a list of all the observations, it then gets normalized into an array called train.
Currently my formatting for the LSTM is as follows:

```
#data
    inputs=[]
target=[]
for i in range(336,train.size-48):
    inputs.append(train[i-336:(i+1),0])
    target.append(train[(i+48),0])
inputs,target=np.array(inputs),np.array(target)
inputs=np.reshape(inputs,(inputs.shape[0],inputs.shape[1],1))

#model
model_in=Input(shape=(inputs.shape[1],1))
hidden=LSTM(50,return_sequences=True)(model_in)
```

There aren't any errors and the results run okay. I am really wondering if this is optimal or fully correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'off the shelf' method to create your dataset.

It has been empirically observed that the sliding window with a step of 1(in your case, half an hour), proves to work well in many situations; it may be the case(depending on the problem) that a step of 1 does not make sense, hence the need of choosing another value.

The only way you can clearly verify your assumptions/possible improvements, is by implementing your ideas.

In your case, this boils down to:

- Either increase/decrease your window_size (every 1 hour or more/every 15 minutes)
- Modify the architecture of the LSTM. Note however that LSTMs are prone to overfitting very fast, so always use a validation set when you increase the output dimension size(dimension of cells (LSTM(**cell_dimension**,return_sequences=True/False(in case you use multiple stacked LSTM layers)

Comment: Your answer has given me good insights thank you. To clarify, for the optimal form of the shape of the **data**, it is really just a trial and error? I hadn't been using a validation set so that information is useful!

Comment: The usage of validation set is crucial, as you can clearly see if you have the phenomenon of **overfitting**. The optimal form of the shame is not necessarily trial and error, but dependent on the problem.